# Logical operators on enums

Tags: c#, enums

Given an enum with 4 elements

```
enum fontType {bold,italic,underlined,struck}
```

and two variables of this enumeration type called enum1 and enum2 that are assigned as follows

```
fontType enum1=fontType.bold | fontType.italic;
fontType enum2=fontType.underlined & fontType.struck;
```

Why is enum1 = 'italic' and enum2 = 'underlined' on output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to use the enum as a bitmap like this, then the members need to be given values which use a different bit each:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
   Bold = 0x01,
   Italic = 0x02,
   Underlined = 0x04,
   Struck = 0x08
}
```

By default, they've been given the numbers 0,1,2,3 - the first does nothing, and the second two overlap with the last.

As mentioned in the comments, you should also add the `[Flags]` attribute to the enum definition, so that if you do `ToString()` you get a properly formatted result (and so that everybody knows how you're using the enum) - if won't affect the way it works if you don't, though.

Comment: ... and [Flags] on the enum as well.

Comment: Yes, if you omit [Flags] then the .ToString() doesn't work as well as it could (it just gives you the numeric value rather than each set flag name)